# CI internal error, type mismatch between kernel parameter 1 and argument

Tags: xcode, uiimage, core-graphics, core-image, cifilter

I am trying to create a CIColorClampFilter
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIColorClamp

It says I can set a key for "inputMinComponents" as a [0,0,0,0] or whatever RGB values I want.

But this code:

```
filter = CIFilter(name:"CIColorClamp")
filter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
filter.setValue([0,0,0,0], forKey: "inputMinComponents")
```

Causes this error:

```
CI internal error, type mismatch between kernel parameter 1 and argument
```

I've look around for other CIColorClamp examples but found nothing.

Do you know whats wrong with the value I'm trying to pass for the "inputMinComponents" key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently swift's smart casting does not work you must explcitly create a CIVector

```
filter = CIFilter(name:"CIColorClamp")
filter.setValue(ciImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
var lowerLevel = CIVector(x: 0.1, y: 0.1, z: 0.3, w: 0)
filter.setValue(lowerLevel, forKey: "inputMinComponents")
var upperLevel = CIVector(x: 0.5, y: 0.7, z: 0.9, w: 1)
filter.setValue(upperLevel, forKey: "inputMaxComponents")
```

Comment: Swift doesn't automatically cast everything. In fact, it requires explicit casts and conversions in more places than C does. You could make the code in your question work with automatic conversion if you extend `CIVector` with an appropriate `ArrayLiteralConvertible` implementation, though.